# c# hight memory used. for ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, usb

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serialcek));
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    t.Start();
  }

public void serialcek()
{

    ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
    try
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
            try
            {
                serial = theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                textBox1.Text = serial;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Bişiler oldu bende anlamadım");

            }

        }
        Thread.Sleep(sure);
        serialcek();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Patladım ben." + ex.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

use thread. but i can't stop it. thread always run and application used memory high.
give an error a few mins later.  maybe i can't use for function  true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call the thread's method recursively without any exit condition. That will eventually lead to a `StackOverflowException`.

Instead of this approach, you should place a `while` loop inside you thread's method. **This is of course implemented roughly, just to give you the idea:**

```
bool exitThread;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serialcek));
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    exitThread = false;
    t.Start();
  }

public void serialcek()
{

    ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
    while (! exitThread)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
                try
                {
                    serial = theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                    textBox1.Text = serial;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Bişiler oldu bende anlamadım");

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Patladım ben." + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Moved Sleep into 'finally' block to make it be called even if an exception occurs
            Thread.Sleep(sure);
    }    
}
```

And then you can exit this thread anytime you like by simply assigning `true` to `exitThread`:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exitThread = true;
}
```